# Visual Studio add-in to support images inline with source?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, documentation, add-in, code-editor

We use Visual Studio 2005 here, and in an attempt to improve the documentation of our source, we're looking for a Visual Studio add-in that will allow images to be viewed in line with source from within the IDE.

For example, the use case I'd like to fit is the following:

1. In the directory in which my source lives, I save my image file `my_image.png`.
2. In the source file, I write a comment of the form `/// @image my_image.png`
3. The add-in allows me to toggle between seeing the text `/// @image my_image.png` and viewing the actual image within the code editing window, inline with whatever source surrounds it.

Does anyone know of an existing add-in for VS 2005? If not, does the VS add-in api allow for such functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is extremely difficult, if possible at all, to do this until Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: I feared as much. Do you have any reference to how it is possible in 2010?

Comment: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/793d16d0-235a-439a-91df-4ce7c721df12